# Showing webpage if user just changed password

Tags: c#

I am using directory services to get the last date the user changed his password.  If this date was within 5 minutes I want to show a particular webpage when the user logs in.  So for example a user gets prompted to change password.  Rigth after changing windows password they login, because the change was within the 5 minute time frame the user will be presented with say google.com.  If the user logs off and logs back in tomorrow nothing would happen.  Here are some ideas I had but don't work.

```
if(datepasswordchanged < datepasswordchanged.AddMinutes(5))
```

However this would happen everytime.

I also had

```
if(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5) == datepasswordchanged)
```

however this would only happen if it was exactly 5 minutes ago.  How could I specify a range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(DateTime.Now < datepasswordchanged.AddMinutes(5))
```

will be "If current time is less than five minutes after time in variable."